# How to debug dropping a file to the .exe

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I want to create a program "foo.exe". I want to drop files on foo.exe and the program should know the filename of the dropped file. I know, that this can be done with command line args, but I do not have an idea, how I can debug this, or "simulate" during coding.

Thanks for your answer :)
I want to use MonoDevelop on Ubuntu.

Florian

Answer (score 3):

To debug such thing, right click your project and open the Properties/Settings, navigate to the Debugging-Tab and configure the arguments at the startup options

Comment: The problem is, that I do not know, how it looks like (Noone specifies that manually, Windows / Linux does.... So, what is the argument, if I drop the file T:/est.exe ? Is it just the path?? An example would be extreamly helpful...

Comment: @Reisi007 Try adding a `MessasgeBox` to your executable  and use it to display the CommandLine args that are passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to provide a comment, so I have to do this as an answer.

Are you asking for code examples or are you asking about how to create a test case for your code?  In either case it might help to provide a sample of your code and then we can either provide help to improve it or at least know what your code is doing so we can provide help on how to test it.

When you say "command-line" are you passing this into an object that you can print out?  If you add the argument as a run-time argument via MonoDevelop, you should be able to at least test out your file handling code first.  Use different examples of files as arguments.  To test "drag-n-drop", you'll have to use print commands to help in debugging to see if you're grabbing the data you need.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for not answering.....
I want the following (explaind differently):
When I open LibO Writer it starts swriter.exe
When I open a document, which is associated with LibO Writer, how does it look like. In C# it is in the string[] args, I guess args[0]....